# How to setup a htaccess to a subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess right now:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

It works if i setup my script on root folder, but if i create a new folder called `'api'` and move all my script to there, does not work as expected and i see a blank page.

I modified the .htacess like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: what is unclear? i have a php script that use index.php as a entry point... i need the htacess configure to redirect, for example, /user/find/1 to my index.php that is located at api folder

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional comment that you might find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not entirely clear from the config, but there are two different path mechanisms:

```
RewriteBase /api/
```

This is "relative" to the request (or browser). i.e. `https://example.com/api/`

However...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/index.php [QSA]
```

That is 'relative' to the server. So inside the server, you would need to have literally that file in a root directory called 'api'.

In short, I believe that what you need is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/index.php [QSA]
```

(note the missing starting slash - which means path relative to the document root and not absolute server path)

---

On a side-note, with `RewriteBase /api/`, it effectively means you do not care about other (undefined) root paths (e.g. `/api2/xx` won't be matched). Therefore there may be an even easier way to your original problem: just move your original `.htaccess` file into the api directory.

Comment: ohh... this worked... the slash it was the problem